# Dynamically add button and remove the last button created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I create an Add button that will dynamically add New button. Also I would like to delete the last created button when I click delete button. How can I do that?

```
public class Stack extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stack);
    final LinearLayout dynamicButtonsLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynalayout);

    final int iNumberOfButtons =  1;
    final Button[] dynamicButtons = new Button[iNumberOfButtons];

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsButton = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsButton.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
    Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button removeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int num=0; //ID INCREMENT
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < iNumberOfButtons; i++) {
                dynamicButtons[i] = new Button(Stack.this);
                dynamicButtons[i].setText(String.valueOf(num));
                dynamicButtons[i].setId(num);
                dynamicButtons[i].setTextSize(15.0f);
                dynamicButtons[i].setLayoutParams(paramsButton);
                dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.addView(dynamicButtons[i]);
                removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //I WANT REMOVE THE VIEW IN THE LAST BUTTON

                    }
                });
            }
            num=num+1;
        }
    });


       ; // dynamicButtonsLinearLayout is the container of the buttons

  }
}
```

Here is the Design of my XML and it show the buttons that I created dynamically

[image]

Comment: It'd be much easier with a Java Stack or List object instead of an Array

Comment: And you want `removeButton.setOnClickListener` outside of that for loop...

Comment: @cricket_007 Java Stack as in like stack and push? Can you please give me an example? It will be a great help. Thank youuu

Comment: Yes, though you'll need to rename your activity. `java.util.Stack`. I trust you to find your own examples

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah. So I did it. I construct my code. I remove the the array and I use a dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.removeViewAt(dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1 ); to remove the button.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank youuuuu very much. :)

Comment: Welcome :) I was on a phone, so couldn't really answer. You are welcome to include your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I change in my code so it can add(Like push) and delete(pop). Sort of Stack Visualization I guess.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount()==0)
            {
                removeButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < iNumberOfButtons; i++) {
                dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount();
                dynamicButtons = new Button(Stack.this);
                dynamicButtons.setText(String.valueOf(dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount()));
                dynamicButtons.setId(num);
                dynamicButtons.setTextSize(15.0f);
                dynamicButtons.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
                dynamicButtons.setLayoutParams(paramsButton);
                dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.addView(dynamicButtons);
            }

            num=num+1;
        }
    });
        removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.removeViewAt(dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1 );
                if (dynamicButtonsLinearLayout.getChildCount()==0)
                {
                    removeButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    removeButton.setEnabled(true);
                }

        }
    });
```